# Finding 2nd maximum in crosstab of Cognos Anlytics

Tags: max, analytics, cognos

I am using `Cognos Analytic` `v11` (with a dimensional DB).

I have a table showing the 24-hour readings of sensor `A`, `B` and `C`. Finding the maximum in crosstab is easy using the `Summarize` function; but how do I find the 2nd maximum (i.e 2nd highest)?

Comment: When you say "2nd maximum" do you mean the second highest value?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: Can you provide the expression you are currently using to get the maximum?

Comment: Also, is the source relational or dimensional?

Comment: Maximum can be derived from Summarize function which applied straight away. So, I do not need to create an expression for it. I would like to know how 2nd maximum, meaning the second highest can be derived. Source is dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work for me:

```
aggregate([{Amount Field}] within set subset(order([{Sensor Field}],[{Amount Field}],DESC),1,1))
```

Replace {Amount Field} with the name of the actual amount data item and {Sensor Field} with the item you want to find the 2nd maximum within.

The order function sorts the set by the amount field. The first member of the resulting set is the maximum. The second member of the resulting set is the 2nd maximum. We isolate the second maximum by using the subset function to get the member with index 1 and then we aggregate the measure for this one member.

Comment: Hi, is it possible for you to provide the query expression in full?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I did provide the expression in full.